# Class type as parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, type-hinting

I am a bit stuck with the type hinting in TypeScript when the parameter is class of specific type. I am trying to implement an event system and when I use the code from TypeScript playground, everything works fine for pure JavaScript. However, the standard compilation cause Errors of "TS2693: 'C1' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here." How can I type-hint this method?

```js
function method
<C1 extends BaseClass, C2 extends BaseClass>
(c1: typeof C1, c2: typeof C2, callback: (arg1: C1, arg2: C2) => void){
    // ...
}
```

Full example:

```js
abstract class BaseClass {}

const dict = {}

function method
<C1 extends BaseClass, C2 extends BaseClass>
(c1: typeof C1, c2: typeof C2, callback: (arg1: C1, arg2: C2) => void){
    dict[c1] = dict[c1] || {};
    dict[c1][c2] = dict[c1][c2] || [];
    dict[c1][c2].push(callback);
}


class MyClass1 extends BaseClass{}
class MyClass2 extends BaseClass{}


method(MyClass1, MyClass2, (arg1: MyClass1, arg2: MyClass2) => {
    console.log("Callback");
});

const c1 = new MyClass1();
const c2 = new MyClass2();
dict[MyClass1][MyClass2][0](c1, c2);
```

Comment: The link does not contain the code. Could you also post a full example with usage example.

Comment: I think here `(c1: typeof C1, c2: C2, callback: (arg1: C1, arg2: C2) => void)` you don't need `typeof` before `C1`

Answer (score 3):

Classes in TypeScript don't behave like you think. Check this snippet out, straight from the TS interpreter:

```
~ ts-node
> class a {}
undefined
> typeof a
'function'
```

It shows that `a` is just a function, so that parameter type hint will evaluate to the literal string `'function'`!

```
> function b(param: a) { console.log(param) };
> b(a)
[Function: a]
> b(new a())
a {}
```

The above code is an example of how to properly use class types as parameters. No need for `typeof`. In your code it could look something like this:

```
function method
<C1 extends BaseClass, C2 extends BaseClass>
(c1: C1, c2: C2, callback: (arg1: C1, arg2: C2) => void){
    // ...
}
```

If what you mean is you want to actually pass *the class type* itself, then you need to work around TS's reflection limitations. You can pass the type as a function that returns a type:

```
function method
<C1 extends BaseClass, C2 extends BaseClass>
(c1: new () => C1, c2: new () => C2, callback: (arg1: C1, arg2: C2) => void){
    new c1() instanceof C1; // true
    new c2() instanceof C2 // true
    c1 instanceof C1 // false
}
```

Tada!